# Count folder inside the folder

Tags: c#

Can you help me how to count the folders inside the folder.

How can i count the sub folders after the FolderBrowserDialog is popup and choose that main folder consist of 3 folders.

I'm using

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbdialog = new FolderBrowswerDialog();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `System.IO.DirectoryInfo()` class and its methods.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [Recursive File and Directory Method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/recursively-find-files) to all the list of folders including Count of sub folders in a folder.